# Python Average Maximum Y in n runs

Tags: python, matplotlib, scripting

I am beginning to learn python and I have a question about this code that my friend and I just randomly made up. What would be the correct way to record the highest Y point in 5000 runs and average them.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 5000
p_win = 0.50
stakecounter = 0
wealth = 3.3
lwealth = [3.3]
bet = .1


while wealth  > 0 :
    flip = random.random() <= p_win
    win = 3 if flip else -3
    wealth = wealth + win * bet
    lwealth.append(wealth)
    stakecounter += 1

print(len(lwealth))
plt.plot(lwealth)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to get the maximum in a run:

- Have a variable holding the max value. Eg, start with `maxwealth=0`, and then in your while loop, have `if wealth > maxwealth: maxwealth = wealth` to update maxwealth whenever wealth goes higher. This is a useful method if you aren't storing a list of values, though in your case you are.
- Just use the builtin `max` function on your list at the end: `max(lwealth)` will give you the maximum value in the list.

Now, as to how you get the average maximum over 5000 runs? The easiest way is to loop through your code 5000 times, storing a list of max values, and then just do `sum(maxes)/len(maxes)`. Or, using Mark Colan's answer, accumulate the value with something like `maxtotal += maxwealth` and then divide by n.

For example:

```
import itertools
import random
n = 5000
maxtotal = 0
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, n):
    p_win = 0.50
    stakecounter = 0
    wealth = 3.3
    lwealth = [3.3]
    bet = .1

    while wealth  > 0 :
        flip = random.random() <= p_win
        win = 3 if flip else -3
        wealth = wealth + win * bet
        lwealth.append(wealth)
        stakecounter += 1

    maxtotal += max(lwealth)

print maxtotal/n
```

Note that using numpy might be a good idea with your code, though. Your code looped 5000 times will take a very long time.

Comment: By very long time  do you mean, hours? days?years?milleniums? I can wait, this is interesting.

Comment: Try it with a lower n, which should give an indication.

Answer (score 0):

As a previous answer suggested, one line of code tracks maxwealth

```
if wealth > maxwealth: maxwealth = wealth
```

An easier and faster way to take the average would be to add this line inside the while loop:

```
totalwealth += wealth
```

...and then just after the while loop:

```
avgwealth /= n
```

That is, instead of keeping a list of wealth points to average later, just calculate the total of the wealth points, then divide by the number of wealth points to get the average.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the average they want, however. Instead, they seem to want to run the same code 5000 times, and average the maximum of each run. I'm not quite sure.

Comment: I want it to record the maximum Y in 5000 runs and then average them. It's way to see average maximum wealth using that formula +3-3.

Comment: If you are looking for something different from the solutions discussed below, it would help to explain how what you want is different.